# Issue inserting into stl::map

Tags: c++, stl, function-pointers

I am trying to create a `<function name, function ptr>` pair using `std::map`

```
typedef int(*FnPtr)()

int Foo()
{
    return 1;
}

map<const char*, FnPtr> funcMap;
funcMap.insert("Foo", Foo);        // Error
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: no instance of overloaded function "std:map<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::insert[with _Kty=const char*, _Ty=FnPtr,_Pr=std::less < const char * > , _Alloc=std::allocator< std::pair< const char* const, FnPtr>>]" matches the argument list

argument types are: (const char[3], void())
```

object type is:

```
std::map< const char*, FnPtr, std::less < const char *>, std::allocator< std::pair < const char* const, FnPtr>>>
```

Does `std:map` not support custom types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) takes an `std::pair` as argument, so you need

```
funcMap.insert(std::make_pair("Foo", Foo));
```

This will fix the compilation error, but, assuming you care about the ordering of elements, it's unlikely your `map` will behave as you expect it to. As defined, your keys are going to have arbitrary ordering depending upon the address that the string literals happen to be placed in memory by the compiler because the map comparator is going to compare addresses of the string literals, and not their contents.

If you want the keys to be ordered by the string contents, then the easiest way is to change the `map` to

```
std::map<std::string, FnPtr> funcMap;
```

---

If you want to avoid using `std::string`, and work with string literals only, then you can define a custom comparator for comparing the strings

```
#include <cstring>

struct str_literal_less
{
    bool operator()(char const *l, char const *r) const
    { return std::strcmp(l, r) < 0; }
};
```

Then define the map as

```
std::map<char const *, FnPtr, str_literal_less> funcMap;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert a pair into a map. Try:

```
funcMap.insert(make_pair("Foo", Foo));
```

If you have C++11 support, you can do

```
funcMap.insert({"Foo", Foo});
```

Alternatively, why can't you just do this?

```
funcMap["Foo"] = Foo;
```

Comment: I tried funcMap["Foo"] = Foo. But then when I tried calling the function after that using (int)(*f)() = funcMap["Foo"], it created another entry in funcMap with key "Foo" and value "0x00000000" after this instruction was executed and as a result, it generated an exception when trying to execute the function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change

```
funcMap.insert("Foo", Foo);
```

In

```
funcMap.insert(make_pair("Foo", Foo));
```

For more info you can read here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/